# Symfony2: problems rendering the translation-form with A2lixTranslationFormBundle and Gedmo\DoctrineExtensions Translatable

Tags: forms, symfony, translation, symfony-forms, doctrine-extensions

I'm using `gedmo/doctrine-translations` and `a2lix/translation-form-bundle: 2.*@dev` to translate my entities.

The translation form always renders a *Field* and *Content* but my entity itself doesn't contain a *Field* or *Content* field.

**The form type**

```
$builder->add('translations', 'a2lix_translations');
```

Comment: the constructor comes from the https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/translatable.md#personal-translations.
I don't have any 'field' or 'content' fields

Comment: the AbstractPersonalTranslation have this 'field' and 'content' fields

Comment: what version of A2LiX  do you use?

Comment: @denys281 "a2lix/translation-form-bundle": "2.*@dev"

Comment: @nifr I'm following DoctrineExtension and the A2lix docs...

Comment: edited my answer - please try the `a2lix_translations_gedmo` field-type and/or providing the `translatable_class` in the options array and report back.

Comment: @Mauro From documentation `"a2lix/translation-form-bundle": "1.*@dev" if you need to use the old Gedmo strategy`

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle and that is actually using the old Gedmo strategy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `2.0` version of the TranslationFormBundle
 **isn't compatible** with the current `gedmo/doctrine-extensions` version.

See the bundle's **[upgrade notes](https://github.com/a2lix/TranslationFormBundle/blob/master/UPGRADE-2.0.md)**.

You'll need to use the currently unstable branches `wip-v2.4.0` and .

---

**solution:**

Either *update* gedmo/doctrine-extensions ...

```
composer require gedmo/doctrine-extensions:wip-v2.4.0@dev
composer update gedmo/doctrine-extensions
```

... or *downgrade* your a2lix/translation-form-bundle version:

```
composer require a2lix/translation-form-bundle:~1.2
composer update a2lix/translation-form-bundle
```

---

**important notice for the `1.x` version of a2lix/TranslationFormBundle:**

You need to use the `a2lix_translations_gedmo` field-type as described in the [documentation](http://a2lix.fr/bundles/translation-form/1.3.html#bundle-usage).

Further you need to specify the translatable class in the options-array like this:

```
$builder->add('translations', 'a2lix_translations_gedmo', array( 
    'translatable_class' => "Your\Entity" 
);
```

Comment: Field 'name' doesn't exist in XXXX\XXXBundle\Entity\EntityTranslation ;-(