# sf 2.6 A2LiX entityTranslation doesn't found

Tags: symfony, translation, a2lix-translation

I just want to make a multilingual application site so I red and saw translatable and other bundle.

I use translatable and a2lix... so I read the doc but when I try to use a2lix, I get this error message :

```
Class c2c\AppBundle\Entity\PeriodTranslation does not exist 500 Internal Server Error - ReflectionException
```

I set my entityTranslation in a subfolder like so Entity>Translation>MyEntityTranslation

Is there a way to say to a2lix... that it should look inside my sub-folder ?

Thank you for your help.

**Entity**

```
namespace c2c\AppBundle\Entity;

use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Translatable\Translatable;


/**
 * Period
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Periods")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="c2c\AppBundle\Entity\PeriodRepository")
 * @Gedmo\TranslationEntity(class="c2c\AppBundle\Entity\Translation\PeriodTranslation")
 */
class Period implements Translatable
...
```

**Entity Translation**

```
namespace c2c\AppBundle\Entity\Translation;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Translatable\Entity\MappedSuperclass\AbstractTranslation;

/**
 * PeriodTranslation is used fo
 *
 * @author blucas
 */


/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="ext_translations_period", indexes={
 *      @ORM\Index(name="period_translation_idx", columns={"locale", "object_class", "field", "foreign_key"})
 * })
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Gedmo\Translatable\Entity\Repository\TranslationRepository")
 */
class PeriodTranslation extends AbstractTranslation
{
    /**
     * All required columns are mapped through inherited superclass
     */
}
```

**Config**

```
orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            gedmo_translatable:
                type: annotation
                prefix: Gedmo\Translatable\Entity
                dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Translatable/Entity"
                alias: GedmoTranslatable
                is_bundle: false
...
# Soft Doctrine extendions
stof_doctrine_extensions:
    default_locale: en_US

    # Only used if you activated the Uploadable extension
    # uploadable:
        # Default file path: This is one of the three ways you can configure the path for the Uploadable extension
        # default_file_path:       %kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads

        # Mime type guesser class: Optional. By default, we provide an adapter for the one present in the HttpFoundation component of Symfony
        # mime_type_guesser_class: Stof\DoctrineExtensionsBundle\Uploadable\MimeTypeGuesserAdapter

        # Default file info class implementing FileInfoInterface: Optional. By default we provide a class which is prepared to receive an UploadedFile instance.
        # default_file_info_class: Stof\DoctrineExtensionsBundle\Uploadable\UploadedFileInfo
    orm:
        default:
            #   sluggable: true
            translatable: true

...

# Give a way to translate form
a2lix_translation_form:
    locale_provider: default
    locales: [en,fr,nl]
    default_locale: en
    required_locales: [en]
    manager_registry: doctrine
    templating: "A2lixTranslationFormBundle::default.html.twig"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is thrown becous the newest version of `a2lix` is not compatible with the stable version of `Gedmo`

check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/22018321/2160958

If you want to use Gedmo strategy you will have to downgrade your `"a2lix/translation-form-bundle"` to `"1.*@dev"` if you want to use the newest version of `"a2lix/translation-form-bundle"` you will have to use 
`wip2.4 Gedmo` version, with is unstable yet.

check this https://github.com/a2lix/TranslationFormBundle/blob/master/UPGRADE-2.0.md

Comment: @ vardius : What is the best solution ? Using new version of a2lix or Gedmo ?

Comment: I recmmend using gedmo for translations but if you need it with a2lix use a2lix translation instead of gedmo.

Comment: I'm new in Symfony and simply in development. If I only use gedmo, is there a way to simply realise a multiple form ? So I can have a form for all language and make only one save ? Sorry for my bad english, I'm hopping that I'm clear.

Comment: the simpliest is to use a2lix translations